# run directive after async call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, lazy-loading

I've build a lazyLoad directive for Angular. The problem is that the attribute value which is the image path is set asynchronously throught $http. At the moment I've set up a $watch on the scope variable. I think this is not the right way to do it? Any suggestions on how to make it work without $watch, $timeout or similar "hackish" methods? :)

This is the directive:

```
angular.module('lazyLoad',[]).directive('lazyLoad', [function() {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        imageSrc: '=lazyLoad'
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

        scope.$watch('imageSrc', function(nVal, oldVal) {

            if (nVal !== oldVal) {
                if (angular.isDefined(scope.imageSrc)) {

                    var img = new Image();

                    img.onload = function() {

                        if (el[0].nodeName !== 'IMG') {
                            el.css('background-image', 'url('+scope.imageSrc+')');
                        }
                        else {
                            el.attr('src', scope.imageSrc);
                        }

                        if (el.hasClass('lazy')) {
                            el.addClass('lazy-loaded');
                        }
                        else {
                            el.parent().addClass('lazy-loaded');
                        }

                    };

                    img.src = scope.imageSrc;

                }                
            }

        });
    }
};

}]);
```

Comment: Try to use `ngIf` on `<img/>` parent, set to `true` before async call, and change it to `false` when you get your image url

Comment: $watch or observe are not "hackish" Angular it self does a lot of watching that being said, you can also use events $broadcast + $on

Comment: Thank you for your answers. ngIf could be a possiblity. The reason why I want to avoid $watch is due to angular performance issues with too many $watches. I've though of $broadcast / $on, but in my opinion its not a very generic solution.

Comment: Just a few pointers. Watching a simple string wouldn't really affect your performance in a noticeable way. Watching complex functions involving loops or deep watching large objects could. You can always unbind the watch when done (if you only need to perform the logic once). Also note that `ngIf` uses watch internally so there wouldn't be any difference in that regard.

Comment: Hey TasseKaTT, great idea unbinding the $watch. I didn't know that ngIf uses an internal watch :) Thanks for clarifying.